# C# Adding Template Class inside a list

Tags: c#, templates

I have Class as such

> CountryRepository

```
public class CountryRepository : BaseRepository<Country>
```

where

> BaseRepository

is

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<DT> : IRepository<DT>
    where DT : IDomainEntity
```

and

> IRepository

as

```
public interface IRepository<DT>
    where DT : IDomainEntity
```

I want to store the class in a list as such

```
this.Repositories = new List<BaseRepository<IDomainEntity>>();
var o = new CountryRepository();
this.Repositories.Add(o);
```

> Error 4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CountryRepository' to
>   'BaseRepository'

Its not working, where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where am I going wrong

`CountryRepository` derives from `BaseRepository<Country>` which is not assignment compatible with `BaseRepository<IDomainEntity>` type expected by  `List`.

Here is how it can be fixed:

Option 1: Make a *non-generic* abstract class the root of class hierarchy and derive the generic class from it.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository

public abstract class BaseRepository<DT>: BaseRepository, IRepository<DT>
   where DT: IDomainEntity

public class CountryRepository: BaseRepository<Country>


this.Repositories = new List<BaseRepository>();
var o = new CountryRepository();
this.Repositories.Add(o);
```

Option 2: Interface covariance. It will work if `DT` is used only as output parameter type, method return type or a read-only property type in `IRepository` declaration.

```
public interface IRepository<out DT> where DT: IDomainEntity

public abstract class BaseRepository<DT> : IRepository<DT>
  where DT : IDomainEntity

public class CountryRepository : BaseRepository<Country>

// Note the usage of IRepository<IDomainEntity>, not BaseRepository 
this.Repositories = new List<IRepository<IDomainEntity>>();   
var o = new CountryRepository();
this.Repositories.Add(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between

```
BaseRepository<Country>
```

and BaseRepository.

Your CountryRepository is derived from

```
BaseRepository<Country>
```

and not from BaseRepository, thus you get the error.

Assign the inheritance right:

```
public class CountryRepository : BaseRepository
```